# Laravel Carbon difference in time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

So I have this table with a start time and an end time and I am calculating hours.
This works just fine unless the end time is midnight.

I have TIME fields in my database for start and end.

This is the calculation

```
      @php 
        $start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($person->clocked_in_at);
        $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($person->clocked_out_at);
        $diff = $start->diff($end)->format('%H:%I');
      @endphp
```

If the start time is 07:30:00 and the end time is 13:00:00 it properly calculates to 05:30 hours. However if the start time is 23:30:00 and the end time is 00:00:00 which should calculate to 30 minutes, it calculates to 23:30:00

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you think it's likely that there will be more than 24 hours between these times?

Comment: @Ebi if there's more than 24 hours then the task becomes impossible. Otherwise it's a simple check to see if $start > $end and adjusting things accordingly.

Comment: 00:00 is on THE FOLLOWING DAY, but you are ignoring the date so the diff becomes eg Monday 00:00 to Monday 23:30, and not Monday 23:30 to Tuesday 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clocked_out is less than the clocked-in then you need to factor in the date change.

```
      @php 
        $start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($person->clocked_in_at);
        $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($person->clocked_out_at);

        @php
          if($end->lt($start) {
             $end->addDay();
          }
        @endphp

        $diff = $start->diff($end)->format('%H:%I');
      @endphp
```

This should also work for other cross-midnight shifts not just those that end exactly at midnight

Blade view is not the place to be doing this calculation though.

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this **year-month-day**

like this:

```
    $start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2015-5-5 23:30:00');
    $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2015-5-6 00:00:00');
    $diff = $start->diff($end)->format('%H:%I');
```

**note**: the day is begining on 00:00:00

hopefully that is help you

Comment: hmmm... sadly this database doesn't record the day. I may end up not being able to do this as I hoped.